# How to run a script on an EC2 instance remotely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance and I need to download a file from its D drive through my program. Currently, it's a very annoying process because I can't access the instance directly from my local machine. The way what I am doing now is running a script on the instance and the instance uploads the file I need to S3 and my program access S3 to read the file.

Just wonder whether there is any simple way to access the drive on the instance instead of going through S3?

Comment: By access means how do you want to access it? By HTTP method or some thing like that. And you access it through S3 so how do you access it through S3 by going to AWS Dashboard?

Comment: To answer the question in your post: You could install an HTTP server or an SFTP server or something on the instance to expose those files. To answer the question in your title: look into the AWS SSM service. Also please note that Stackoverflow.com is for programming questions. Your question probably belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

I have used AWS DataPipeline and its task runner to execute scripts on a remote instance.  The taskrunner waits for a pipeline event published to its worker group.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-using-task-runner.html
I use it to execute shell script and commands on a schedule.  The script to run should be uploaded to S3, and the Data pipeline template specifies the script's path.  Works great for periodic tasks.  You can do anything you want on the remote box via the script.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot directly download the file from EC2, but via s3( or maybe using scp command) from your remote ec2.
But to simplify this annoying process you can use AWS Systems Manager.

AWS Systems Manager Run Command allows you to remotely and securely run set of commands on EC2 as well on-premise server. Below are high-level steps to achieve this.

Attach Instance IAM role:
The ec2 instance must have IAM role with policy AmazonSSMFullAccess. This role enables the instance to communicate with the Systems Manager API.

Install SSM Agent:
The EC2 instance must have SSM agent installed on it. The SSM Agent process the run command requests & configure the instance as per command.

Execute command :
Example usage via AWS CLI:

Execute the following command to retrieve the services running on the instance. Replace Instance-ID with ec2 instance id.

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --comment "listing services" --instance-ids "Instance-ID" --parameters commands="service --status-all" --region us-west-2 --output text
```

More detailed information: https://www.justdocloud.com/2018/04/01/run-commands-remotely-ec2-instances/